# DB2 embedded SQL in C use same host variable for both input and output allowed?

Tags: sql, c, db2, embedded-sql

Is it safe to use same host variable for both input and output in an embedded SQL query ?
I'm using C and DB2 static embedded SQL.

Example:

```
EXEC SQL 
     SELECT someCol 
     INTO :someHostVar 
     FROM SomeTable 
     WHERE :someHostVar = someOtherCol;
```

Comment: I wouldn't do it that way just because I'd want more descriptive names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. The value of `someHostVar` will be overwirtten and contain whatever the value of `someCol` is for this particular predicate - unless the value of `someCol` happens to be NULL at which point it the host variable remains unchanged.

Even though you can do this, I would suggest to you that this is not a good practice because `someHostVar` may end up containing values for different columns of the same table - too easy to screw up.